# Removing Mitsubishi Galant 2000 V6 Engine

Tags: engine

How do I remove a Mitsubishi Galant 2000 V6 engine? I have the wires and everything disconnected, but I am not sure if I am supposed to take the transmission off, or just pull it out transmission and all. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you have the option of either unbolting the transmission or removing the axles and then pulling the motor/tranny in one piece

[edit]  I forgot.. this is also assuming you've unbolted the engine mounts?

Comment: Do you have access to a lift? Might be easier to drop everything all together from the bottom.